# Add math delimiters in ikiwiki and mathjax

Tags: pandoc, ikiwiki

In my `ikiwiki` + `pandoc` + `mathjax` setup the delimiters `$` for inline math and `$$` for display math are currently recognized. How can I add additional delimiters, for example `\(` and `\)` for inline and `\[` and `\]` for display math?

Note that I already posted the same question on the [ikiwiki forum](https://ikiwiki.info/forum/How_to_add_additional_math_delimites_for_pandoc_plugin/) but didn't receive an answer for a long time, so I try it here again.